# Using 'if' inside two 'while' loops in bash -- 'if' completed skipped

Tags: server, 20.04, bash, scripts

I already looked for "using if inside a while loop bash" and haven't found my situation.

I have a text file that is a list of devices. Each line in the text file is a short string without whitespace.
This is the text file:

```
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sdb
```

I wrote a script that reads the text file line-by-line (the first 'while' loop).
For each line, 'df' is called using "dev/$line" as input. 'df' outputs 2 lines into stdout. Using a pipe, the output from df is read line-by-line (the second 'while' loop).
I know the nested 'while' loops and the pipe from 'df' to 'while read' are working fine, because I can use 'echo' to print each line from 'df' to the console.

My issue is that I have added 'if' condition to test, but the 'if' seems to just be skipped! Nothing outputs for that portion of my script... even though it should echo "not found" if the 'if' condition fails.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#list the devices in /dev, save list of devices beginning in sd
ls /dev | grep -E 'sd' > /home/testuser/grepout.txt
#iterate through the list and check its mountpoint
input=/home/testuser/grepout.txt
bootdev=''
echo "$bootdev is not set"
#if the mountpoint is boot, then save the dev name
while read line
do
        echo "checking mountpoint of $line"
        counter=0
        df /dev/"$line" --output=target | while read line2
        do
                echo $counter
                ((counter++))
                if [ "$line2"="/boot" ]
                then
                        echo "$line2"
                        bootdev="$line"
                else
                        echo "Not found"
                fi
        done
done < "$input"
```

Here is the output:

```
 is not set
checking mountpoint of sda
0
Mounted on
1
/dev
checking mountpoint of sda1
0
Mounted on
1
/dev
checking mountpoint of sda2
0
Mounted on
1
/boot
checking mountpoint of sda3
0
Mounted on
1
/dev
checking mountpoint of sdb
0
Mounted on
1
/dev
```

Comment: `if [ "$line2"="/boot" ]` will always be true - see for example [How does bash interpret the equal operator with no surrounding spaces in a conditional?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/how-does-bash-interpret-the-equal-operator-with-no-surrounding-spaces-in-a-condi) and [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Comment: Thank you!! 
I continued searching after posting this, and found 'shellcheck'.net. I was able to correct my syntax with its help.

Comment: Ah good - shellcheck gets a thumbs up from me

Comment: The first link you posted explained the issue exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the specific goal is to know the nested loop operator behavior, or to find the bootvolume, but in your shoes I've solved that problem in the past avoiding the nested while loops since I find them confusing to read and maintain:

```
#!/bin/bash

for disk in `find /dev/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*sd\*`; do
 if df $disk | grep '/boot'; then
        echo "$disk is bootvolume!"
 fi
done
```

Comment: Is `find` really necessary here? wouldn't a simple shell glob `for disk in /dev/sd*` suffice?

Comment: Haha, my script was more an exercise to test out my understanding of bash, but your suggestion is very helpful. I would like to keep my code more concise and I think I could adapt this to my needs.

Comment: For this example, shell glob works as well!  Lotsa ways to do it.  :-)